# List of installed repositories (yum)

Tags: yum, repository

In CentOS how can I get a list of installed repositories?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
yum repolist
yum repolist enabled
```

shows all enabled repositories. Those two commands are identical.

```
yum repolist disabled
```

shows disabled repositories.

```
yum repolist all
```

shows everything.

```
yum repolist --verbose
```

shows detailed information, including the URL.

Comment: superb answer... How to enable disabled repos?

Comment: Edit the corresponding file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`.

Comment: to enable a repo: `yum-config-manager --enable <repo>`, to disable: `yum-config-manager --disable <repo>`.

Comment: How to see the url's for each? :)

Answer (score 19):

This is the path of yum repository

> [root@localhost yum.repos.d]# pwd
>
> /etc/yum.repos.d

This is the content of that directory

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# ll
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  179 Jul 17 11:56 adobe-linux-i386.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1926 Jun 26 14:59 CentOS-Base.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  637 Jun 26 14:59 CentOS-Debuginfo.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  626 Jun 26 14:59 CentOS-Media.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2593 Jun 26 14:59 CentOS-Vault.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  912 Jan 23  2011 elrepo.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  957 May  9 21:25 epel.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1056 May  9 21:25 epel-testing.repo
.
.
.
```

The difference between `yum.conf` and `yum.repos.d` is
in earliar system yum.conf (`/etc/yum.conf`) was using, within a single file we have to configure everything it was very congesting so now what they did is, they created several repo files, instead of one repo file and all the repos are kept under /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory.

Answer (score 8):

[This Page](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Yum_and_Yum_Repositories.html) indicates that yum keeps individual repository settings in `the  [repository] sections in  /etc/yum.conf and  .repo files in the  /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory`. You should be able to see all the repositories from these two places. The link is about Redhat so YMMV.

From [this link](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Viewing_the_Current_Configuration.html) (also red hat), `yum-config-manager repository` might (or might not) achieve the same as above.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add:

```
yum -v repolist all
```

in case the server is using Spacewalk or part of RedHat this can be very useful to find the Repository URL.

**NOTE:** If the server is registered to Spacewalk there will be no entries under /etc/yum.repos.d/ 
At least using the command to register like :

```
rhnreg_ks --activationkey=<key> --serverUrl=http://<server>/XMLRPC
```